# SQL Server Character Encoding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

There is an nvarchar column in our table, using collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Two records in there, with visually the same value:

```
AM209405
AM209405
```

These relate to Greek accounts. However...when we look at the ASCII values of the characters we get this:

[image]

The top one has A and M with the standard codes. The bottom one has A and M both with the same code of 63.

Therefore, when we compare, no rows are returned:

```
select *
from dbo.mytable a
inner join dbo.mytable b on b.TheValue = a.TheValue
```

I am looking for way, either via collate or some other method, to show them as a match, something like this (which doesn't work):

```
select *
from dbo.mytable a
inner join dbo.mytable b on b.TheValue = a.TheValue collate greek_ci_as
```

The only other way I can think of is to create some sort of mapping table that equates the two as being the same.

Any advice appreciated and I'm open to any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: `ascii()` - if that's what your using in your test - is of little utility when dealing with unicode, clearly the 2nd `M = 65`  is not correct and is likely the truncation of a multi-byte value.  `cast(the_col as varbinary(max))` will show you the byte encoding for the values so you can see the difference.

Comment: Obviously the ASCII value is not correct because those characters don't fit in ASCII. Use `UNICODE` or `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), [column])` to see the actual code point. I'm assuming it's `U+039C GREEK CAPITAL LETTER MU`, but that's not obvious from the question.

Comment: A quick test shows that there is no T-SQL collation that will compare a Latin capital letter M and a Greek capital letter Mu as equal, so if that's your scenario, a mapping table (or an inline table-valued function with the mapping) seems unavoidable.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, when comparing the varbinary, they are different.  Either way, they are different, and will not return when compared in my select.  I'm looking for way to have them returned in a select, either via collation or some other way, but as per JeroenMostert this may not be possible without an interim mapping table.

Comment: @marc_s  You edited my question from "an nvarchar" to "a nvarchar". This is incorrect".  Please google the rules of English: "Use AN before words such as "hour" which sound like they start with a vowel even if the first letter is a consonant".

Comment: If the Greek Mu is supposed to represent the Latin M and is some kind of transcription/input error then why not just replace it (preferably at the insertion point) - `replace(value, nchar(0x039C), N'M')`

Comment: @marc_s,  say "egg"....(e)nvarchar.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. Yes will probably go down that route, unfortunately at the comparison end not the insertion but that's not up to me.  Thanks for your help.